# immature share in bitcoin gold PPLNS system

Tags: bitcoin

I mine BTG and would like to know what is immature share?
Will it be added to balance?
If yes, then when?
On what it depends?
Why it is bigger than balance?
http://joxi.ru/VrwnyjQHKzOjGA

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. You should post things like this on https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Even if you think it is "bad" question you could at least show respect for David, who spent his time to answer.

Comment: Users here shouldn't answer off-topic questions. Maybe David did not know this. I don't think the question is "bad", I think it is off-topic according to the [Help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I wanted to close it but received warning that I'll not be able to post questions in the future and so on.. So where is the button "move question to bitcoin.stackexchange"?

Comment: No problem, it will be closed eventually. Here is more info about migration -- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work

Comment: I can't delete question and day after day someone press downvote. How to remove this question? Wait untill SO admin close it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Immature shares mean that they are shares of coins that cannot be transferred or spent yet. When they become mature (in 100 blocks for bitcoin gold) the pool should begin to payout the shares.

Comment: Is there a way to calculate the moment " When they become mature (in 100 blocks for bitcoin gold "  ?

Comment: If you know what block was mined, just add 100 to its block number and when that block is mined, they're mature.

Comment: That easy.. Thanks